# Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine issue while launching a training job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I want to train an object detector using Google Cloud Machine Learning Engine and I'm stuck while launching the training part of this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine).

I'm facing this error :

> gapic-google-cloud-logging-v2 0.91.3 has requirement google-gax<0.16dev,>=0.15.7, but you'll have google-gax 0.12.5 which is incompatible.

even after doing

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade google-gax
```

Have you got a solution to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround noted in one of the issues of a [Google CloudML sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/issues/196), that switching to  `pip3` and `python3` allows it to be installed.